# Выдернуть цифры из строки java jsoup

Tags: java, html, парсер, jsoup

Надеюсь последний вопрос на сегодня.Использую библиотеку **jSoup**

Суть вопроса такова. Как извлечь из всего хтмл(а)  цифры  из конкретного тега которые больше в коде не встречаются?  пожалуйста можно примером. 
Честно пролистал очень много ответа не нашел.

```js
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://bcs-express.ru/kotirovki-i-grafiki/gazp").get();
Element title = doc.body();
System.out.println(title);
```

Как из всей этой страницы выдернуть то что находится в теге

```html
<div class="emet_index" data-placeholder="current">138,05</div>
```

Конкретно интересуют данные цифры.138,05

Помогите примером или кодом. Из документации не понял честно!

Comment: Зря вы открыли еще один вопрос. Лучше дополните предыдущий.

Answer (score 0):

```
String html = "<div class='emet_index' data-placeholder='current'>138,05</div>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Element link = doc.select("div").first();
System.out.println(doc.body().text());
```